# border under the Home I go into the info then border during the info and not the front

Tags: html, css

It is such that I have a menu where there is a border in the page you're into, just currently the whole time on the index page, but if I click onto the news as it should be less.

I have tried so many ways but none of them works, think a little that you can do it with something GET?

This means that it must move to find the page you are on, and view page not in the menu so it should not be there.

there are border in Home, how can I do so that, for example, I go into the info then border under the info and not the front, what should I do there?

```
<div class="pi-header-block pi-pull-right">
            <ul class="pi-simple-menu pi-has-hover-border pi-full-height pi-hidden-sm">
                <li class="pi-has-dropdown active"><a href="/"><span>Forside</span></a></li>
                <li class="pi-has-dropdown"><a href="/info/"><span>Info</span></a></li>
                <li class="pi-has-dropdown"><a href="/nyhed/"><span>Nyhed</span></a></li>
                <li class="pi-has-dropdown"><a href="/team/"><span>Team</span></a></li>
                <li class="pi-has-dropdown"><a href="/kontakt/"><span>Kontakt</span></a></li>
                <li class="pi-has-dropdown"><a href="/opret-bruger/"><span>Opret bruger</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Ses image [HER](http://billedeupload.dk/images/cX53.png)

Here you can see how my menu appears when I click on the info.

Comment: I guess the active state, which styles with a `border`, comes from class `active` in `<li class="pi-has-dropdown active">...</li>`. Remove this class and add it to another menu item. How? Well, that really depends. For that, we need more input.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is as simple as this: see the `pi-has-dropdown active` part. If you don't want it, just remove it. If you want it in other pages, add it to each page, for example in Info, like this:

```
<div class="pi-header-block pi-pull-right">
        <ul class="pi-simple-menu pi-has-hover-border pi-full-height pi-hidden-sm">
            <li class="pi-has-dropdown"><a href="/"><span>Forside</span></a></li>
            <li class="pi-has-dropdown  active"><a href="/info/"><span>Info</span></a></li>
            <li class="pi-has-dropdown"><a href="/nyhed/"><span>Nyhed</span></a></li>
            <li class="pi-has-dropdown"><a href="/team/"><span>Team</span></a></li>
            <li class="pi-has-dropdown"><a href="/kontakt/"><span>Kontakt</span></a></li>
            <li class="pi-has-dropdown"><a href="/opret-bruger/"><span>Opret bruger</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

. You usually do this with the help of a CMS or some JS/Jquery coding, but you could totally hard code it on each page if you want. This way, you need to copy this snippet of code on each page, only changing the active class keeping in mind in which page are you. As simple as that